# add data to multidimensional php array

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array that outputs the following:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => wordpress
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => wordpress
            [1] => forms
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => wordpress
            [1] => galleries
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => wordpress
            [1] => ecommerce
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => wordpress
            [1] => ecommerce
            [2] => wp-e-commerce
        )
)
```

How would i go about adding an item into the `[0] => Array`?

This is the way i have created my array:

```
$cats = array();
foreach($items as $x=> $item) {

        $ex = explode("/",$item['path']);
        $cats[] = explode("/",$item['path']);

        echo $item['name'].' - '. $item['path'];
        echo "<br>";
    }

print_r($cats);
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, something like:

```
array_push($cats[0],'something else');
```

should work.

Comment: is there anyway i could do this dynamically?

Comment: glad to hear :) .. another possible option could be keys as strings in your array.